# Docker Gitlab change forgotten root password

Tags: docker, gitlab, root, change-password

I'm running my Gitlab with Docker and 
I forgot my Gitlab root password. How to change it ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found a way to make it work.
First connect to your Gitlab with command line

search for your Docker CONTAINER_ID

`docker ps -all`

eg

[image]

`docker exec -it d0bbe0e1e3db bash` <-- with your CONTAINER_ID

`$ gitlab-rails console -e production`

[image]

```
user = User.where(id: 1).first
user.password = 'your secret'
user.password_confirmation = 'your secret'
user.save
exit
```

Comment: I was not able to login after using this method to update root password. After login the container's terminal, instead of using this method, I update the root password by using the command `gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[root]"`. ([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_user_password.html#rake-task)).

Comment: This proposed solution here worked for me. Remember that gitlab requires both letters and digits in the password. When you do `user.save` you should get a `true`.

Ps. ❤️ rails Ds

Answer (score 44):

The [new-ish hotness](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_user_password.html) to change Gitlab's "root" account's password is this:

```
gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[root]"
```

And if you're running Gitlab inside a Docker container, then use this from the host (you may have to "sudo" this depending on your situation):

```
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[root]"
```

This assumes that you named your Gitlab container "gitlab". And be patient; don't be surprised if it takes more than a few seconds before the "Enter password:" prompt shows up.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, so thanks for sharing!  You were right about being patient, took ~40 seconds to show the prompt in my local dev

Comment: Worked perfectly! It is so annoying that is this not easily found in the official documentation.

Comment: The prompt appeared and it said after I confirmed password: Password successfully updated for user with username root.
But I still can't login into web portal. Did already 3 times with different passwords. Each time same result. I used docker image: gitlab/gitlab-ee:14.10.2-ee.0

Comment: In my case problem can not be solved after I have taken docker volume moved to another machine using `cp -a gitlab /media/flshdrive/gitlab` nd then from flash to another machine. I use same docker image, but Ubuntu on new 22.04 instead of 18.04 and Docker is newer.

Comment: It didn't work for me on mbp M1 arm:
<jemalloc>: MADV_DONTNEED does not work (memset will be used instead)
<jemalloc>: (This is the expected behaviour if you are running under QEMU)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This worked for me as of August 5th 2023. I recommend to write your container id instead of "gitlab" after exec -it (seems basic knowledge but it can be confusing)

Answer (score 1):

I leave a tutorial updated to the new version. In my case it is for a Gitlab installation on a Synology.

Translate (Spanish -> English )
https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&u=https://www.vicolinker.net/synology-gitlab-reset-root-password/

Original (Spanish)
https://www.vicolinker.net/synology-gitlab-reset-root-password/