# gitlab VM your account is pending approval from your GitLab administrator and hence blocked

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am following a tutorial that had me "install" gitlab via docker on my Virtual Box, VM, osboxes@osboxes.  Once the gitlab was "install" completed, I used firefox and entered the static IP address of my osboxes, http://192.168.151.150.

Firefox went straight to a gitlab page requesting username and password (http://192.168.151.150/users/sign_in).  I had no idea what to enter, so I entered register.  Then an attempt to use what I registered states,

"Your account is pending approval from your GitLab administrator and hence blocked. Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is an error."

Any idea what I am supposed to enter as username and password?

This is how I "installed gitlab"
sudo docker run --detach 
--hostname 192.168.151.150 
--publish 192.168.151.150:443:443 
--publish 192.168.151.150:80:80 
--publish 192.168.151.150:9222:22 
--name gitlab 
--restart always 
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab 
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab 
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab 
--shm-size 256m 
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

Comment: I'm not sure this is a topical Stack Overflow question; gitlab is a tool used by programmers, yes, but it's using it as a software developer that's unambiguously on-topic here, as opposed to setting up and configuring the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Gitlab change forgotten root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747402/docker-gitlab-change-forgotten-root-password)

Comment: That link is to a forgotten password.   So how is that question allowed, but not mine?  Lucky for me that I figured out the answer.  
I had googled with no luck nor hint from anywhere, so I thought to share the answer too and that got rejected too.

Comment: There's another suggestion here: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/your-account-is-pending-approval-from-your-gitlab-administrator-and-hence-blocked-please-contact-your-gitlab-administrator-if-you-think-this-is-an-error/59029/5 - any use?